Flask Python : Api response empty when using response custom class
Working on a minimalist project, I am trying to directly return a custom ApiResponse from flask View like this :
@app.route("/signup", methods=["POST"])
def sign_up():
    json_data = request.get_json()
    snake_case_json = to_snake_case(json_data)

    # create user in db
    new_user = create_user(user_attributes=snake_case_json)

    return ApiResponse(
        entity=new_user, status_code=201, message="User created successfully"
    )

ApiResponse class :
from flask import jsonify, Response


class ApiResponse(Response):
    def __init__(self, status_code, entity, message=None):
        response_data = {
            "status": status_code,
            "data": entity.to_dict(),
            "message": message,
        }
        super().__init__(
            response=jsonify(response_data),
            status=status_code,
            content_type="application/json",
        )


User class :
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from back.database import Base


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    first_name = Column(String, unique=False, nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String, unique=False, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "first_name": self.first_name,
            "last_name": self.last_name,
            "email": self.email,
        }

I am using postman for tests, I have a code 201 but an empty body, I am having troubles finding out what's missing.

Let me try to answer, the return type of jsonify function execution result is Response.
The type annotation of the request response returned by the interface is
response: t.Iterable[bytes] | bytes | t.Iterable[str] | str | None = None

So, you can use the following code instead of ApiResponse
class ApiResponse(Response):
    def __init__(self, status_code, entity, message=None):
        response_data = {
            "status": status_code,
            "data": entity.to_dict(),
            "message": message,
        }
        super().__init__(
            response=app.json.dumps(response_data),
            status=status_code,
            content_type="application/json",
        )


Thank you for your help, json.dumps() return a str which is more suitable indeed, something went when I used jsonify from Flash.
